# MS Access VBA Listbox with row colouring?

Tags: ms-access, vba, listbox

I'm trying to put together a little list box, populated from a query, that would have the background colour of its rows as different colours depending on a certain status.

I've done some googling around the subject and it doesn't seem possible using the standard controls that the Access form designer provides. There are some ActiveX controls out there such as ListView and the MS Forms 2.0 Listbox but I can't seem to find any usage guides or references for these controls.

Has anyone had any luck with the above and/or know where do get documentation for the aforementioned ActiveX controls?

Much appreciated,
Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to use a sub-form.  Listbox lines are not individually format-able.

Comment: I would add that a sub-form can be formatted to look a lot like a list box but with all of the power and flexability of a full form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm delighted to report I just found [documentation on ListView](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6027) that may be just what you're looking for.
 (But for myself, I'm sticking with good ol' sub-forms!)